# Do I need to play online over xbox live to save skill points in RE6?

Tags: resident-evil-6

Do I have to choose XBOX LIVE for the Network Selection option to save skill points ?

Or can I just play offline and still get skill points ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked this for myself in the past few days of playing. Skill points are saved even if you play offline.